# How to repair asphalt roof with no decking

Tags: roof, asphalt

I had a windstorm blow a large tree limb through the roof of my shed and I need to repair it. It's one of those pre-made sheds that the previous homeowner likely got installed on-site from Home Depot or similar. Problem is there is no decking on the roof at all, it has 24in studs with what looks like a 1/2" insulation and moisture barrier and that's it.

It's not exactly new, so I'm considering just re-tiling over the existing asphalt for the entire roof but still I'm not quite sure how to properly secure the new tiles with nothing to nail them into except studs every 24in.

Is there any way to repair this other than replacing the entire roof?

Is there a typical way to deal with repairing or re-roofing these or do people normally tear it all the way down to install decking and tile it properly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How/where are the old asphalt shingles attached

Comment: That looks like foil backed Osb.    https://lpcorp.com/products/panels-sheathing/radiant-barrier

Answer (score 1):

Your roof has Osb sheathing for a deck.

This particular roof has used Osb that has a foil overlay on the underside that theoretically blocks some radiant heat from entering the structure.

Repairs and re roofing would proceed as with any roof on OSB.

https://lpcorp.com/products/panels-sheathing/radiant-barrier

Comment: This is definitely it. It looks like the osb got wet, likely from the same branch just denting the roof, but it was super-dark and looked like dirty foam from the ground. I got up there and confirmed it is just discolored osb. Appreciate the response.